# Panda: using lambda function to create a new column by adding two columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am learning lambda function in Panda and i am trying to play around with it, but somehow stuck on a really simple taks, I believe I am really close.

The data frame looks like this

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   3   4
```

I am trying to have the follow data frame:

```
    A   B  C
0   1   2  3
1   2   3  5
2   3   4  8


newSumColumn = lambda x: x['A'] / x['B']
df['C'] = df.apply(newSumColumn)
```

However, when i do this, I ran into `('A', 'occurred at index Unnamed: 0')`

It seems like a simply task, but I banging my head against the wall at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one typo and need add `axis=1`

```
# it is B not b
newSumColumn = lambda x: x['A'] / x['B']
#should add axis=1
df.apply(newSumColumn,axis = 1)
Out[1018]: 
0    0.500000
1    0.666667
2    0.750000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the function is applied along column. To apply along row, you can try:

```
newSumColumn = lambda x: x['A'] / x['b']
df['C'] = df.apply(newSumColumn, axis=1)
```